# How to install remote public X server without compromising machine running it?

Tags: security, xorg, x-server, access-control

I currently have headless rsyslog/network monitoring server which is kind of critical in terms of security and access control. On the other hand this machine stays relatively close to presentation screen and CPU load stays around only 1-2% so It'd be nice to use it as kind of "display controller" serving publicly accessible X server so we wouldn't need to connect cables. The problem is - this machine is quite important in terms of security so this X server should be able to only display picture via X forwarding and absolutely **nothing else** for sure it must not create any chance to break into some account here. Something like "kiosk X server" able to only display remote apps.

Is it possible? Or X server immediately introduces vulnerability and it can't be helped? I could use some virtualization if it can make it safer

Comment: It's possible, but suicidal in terms of security.  Buy a smaller machine for monitoring, and re-purpose this one as an X terminal server if you must.

Comment: I've been using docker for things like this, it's ok in the safety department, but (of course) can't use any resources of the host without you specifically allowing that.